# PUT request works with curl, 422 with fetch

Tags: javascript, curl, jwt, token, sveltekit

I'm building a Svelte app and making a fetch request to my API. When I make a `PUT` request using `fetch`, I receive a `422 (Unprocessable Entity)` error, but when I make the same request using `curl`, it works as expected.

Here is the working `curl` request as shown in the API documentation:

```bash
curl -X 'PUT' \
'http://localhost:8000/auth/users/tokens' \
-H 'accept: application/json' \
-H 'Cookie: refreshToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

This request returns the expected object:

```json
{
  "access_token": "string",
  "refresh_token": "string"
}
```

However, when I try to replicate the same request in my Svelte app using fetch, it fails:

```js
const response = await fetch(`${SITE_DOMAIN}/auth/users/tokens`, {
  method: "PUT",
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Cookie': `refreshToken=${refreshToken}`,
  },
});
console.log(response);
```

i get:

```bash
PUT http://localhost:8000/auth/users/tokens 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
```

I'm not sure why this is happening as the requests appear to be identical. Could it be something to do with how fetch handles cookies or headers compared to curl? Or is there something I'm missing in my fetch request? Any help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT **17-07-2023**

I get the same issue with the API docs, it throws the 422. but when i do the curl directly from the terminal it works:

**

- 422 on the API docs:

**
[image: Docs with the PUT REQUEST DOCUMENTATION]

**

- Sucessfull with CURL:

**
[image: CURL SUCESS]

Comment: You are not sending `Content-Type` header in curl request, are you ?

Comment: Hi @NalinRanjan , just added some screenshots, i think the problem lays in the call being done from the browser vs the call being done directly from the terminal. I guess we can forget my fetch request, since the problem also is visible on the API docs ( which i guess it uses the exact same request that works on the terminal)

Comment: may i ask, why are you sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in `Content-Type` header, though you aren't sending anything in the body ?

Answer (score 0):

In the fetch version you should remove the `Content-Type` header/use the value for `Content-Type` which is mentioned in the API docs. Unprocessable entity 422 occurs when the server request gets a `Content-Type` header for the payload which it does not know how to process. It is also a good practice to add the accept header. Something like this:

```
....
  headers: {
    'Cookie': `refreshToken=${refreshToken}`,
    "accept", "application/json"
  },
  ....
```

Comment: Problem is, the curl on the API Docs (Picture 1) is also not working, but if copy the curl and run it on a terminal it works (Picture2).